# Unable to get access token from json rsponse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am working on implementation of strava in my website. I am new to JavaScript and I am not understanding whether I am doing it correctly or not. My problem is  I am unable to get access token from JSON response. I don't know why. Please Help me.

the resonse what I am getting

[image]

code

```
<script>
    const auth_link = "https://www.strava.com/oauth/token"
function getActivites(res){
console.log('response2',res.json());
    const activities_link = `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?access_token=${res.access_token}`
    fetch(activities_link)
        .then((res) => console.log(res.json()))
}
function reAuthorize(){
    fetch(auth_link,{
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            client_id: 'xxxx',
            client_secret: 'xxxxx',
            refresh_token: 'xxxxx',
            grant_type: 'refresh_token'
        })
    })
    .then(res => {
        var response = res.json();
        var access_token = response.access_token;
        console.log('response',access_token)
       // getActivites(res)
        })
}
reAuthorize()

</script>
```

I am getting access token as `undefined`

Comment: Did you try to await `res.json()`?

Comment: No I didn't try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function reAuthorize() {
  fetch(auth_link, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      client_id: "55077",
      client_secret: "801a8541e8ae55cffee584a48c5bb6a233dea9a0",
      refresh_token: "08342cdf3250da9e0d1b53303fa40faf0d05965d",
      grant_type: "refresh_token"
    })
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: I tried this. it is working fine I don't know how it is working. thank you very much almost I was trying from morning.

Comment: my pleasure. you can find useful network methods on this link https://javascript.info/network

Comment: Jogaleumeshs answer shows the problem perfectly, `response.json()` returns a promise and not JSON. Therefore you need to consume that promise somehow: either with using `.then()` or by using the `await` keyword.